# How to pass arguments like “Country Name” to OpenSSL when creating self signed certificate?

Tags: certificate, openssl

I can create a self-signed certificate using this command

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -x509 -keyout server.key -out server.crt
```

But is it possible to pass arguments like “Country Name,” “State or Province Name” etc. to OpenSSL to automate this process?

Comment: You still need to pass the hostnames through a CONF file. Otherwise, browsers will reject the certificate, even if its in the proper trust store. That's because The [CA/Browser Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/) requires the hostnames in the *Subject Alternate Name*, and the only way to add them is through the CONF file. Also see [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This [website](https://www.shellhacks.com/create-csr-openssl-without-prompt-non-interactive/) explains very well how to do this:

> The magic of CSR generation without being prompted for values which go in the certificate's subject field, is in the `-subj` option.
>
> ```
> -subj arg
>   Replaces subject field of input request with specified data and outputs modified request.
>     The arg must be formatted as /type0=value0/type1=value1/type2=...,
>     characters may be escaped by \ (backslash), no spaces are skipped.
> ```

For example:

```
openssl ... -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Global Security/OU=IT Department/CN=example.com"
```

See more details on the page I linked above.

Comment: Given link points to a non-existing page. Similar information can be found from https://www.shellhacks.com/create-csr-openssl-without-prompt-non-interactive/

Comment: And to include a contact email, append this to the subject: `/emailAddress=me@mydomain.com`

Comment: Does OpenSSL not document the fields it accepts as part of the `-subj` option? A link to the official docs of the tool is what I would hope for here.